# simple cp command problem " i try to copy only "

Tags: copy, cp, copy-and-paste

```
cp: 'test.txt' and 'test.txt' are the same file
asadzoot@asadzoot-Vostro-14-3468:~/cnc/q1$ cp test.txt home/asadzoot/cnc/q1/
cp: cannot create regular file 'home/asadzoot/cnc/q1/': No such file or directory
```

Comment: This line `cp test.txt home/asadzoot/cnc/q1/` should be `cp test.txt /home/asadzoot/cnc/q1/`

Comment: Or `~/asadzoot/cnc/q1/` to abbreviate.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Your command seems off, this:

```
cp test.txt home/asadzoot/cnc/q1/
```

should be:

```
cp test.txt /home/asadzoot/cnc/q1/
```

But of course make sure your running this command from the location of the `test.txt` file.